# Understanding Getting and Setting nodeValue

Tags: javascript, dom

I am updating a text value and I'm not sure why the first block of code doesn't work, but the alternate block does. Can someone explain this to me? They seem equivalent.

//doesn't update

```
newAtomicNum = 2;
oldAtomicNum = document.getElementById("atomicNumber").firstChild.nodeValue;
oldAtomicNum = newAtomicNum;
```

****versus****  //does update

```
newAtomicNum = 2;
oldAtomicNum = document.getElementById("atomicNumber");
oldAtomicNum.firstChild.nodeValue = newAtomicNum;
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `nodeValue` without setting it, it returns the current nodeValue, not a reference to the property.

So an element looking like

```
<div id="atomicNumber">test</div>
```

Where you call

```
var oldAtomicNum = document.getElementById("atomicNumber").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

`oldAtomicNum` now contains **the string** `test`, so setting the variable to something else does not update the elements nodeValue

Comment: So I need to create a reference to the node, before I can set it?

Answer (score 0):

They're very different indeed.

In your first example, all you're updating is the variable, `oldAtomicNum`. There's no enduring link between that and `document.getElementById("atomicNumber").firstChild.nodeValue` at all. Assignment (`=`) copies *values*, it doesn't create references.

Note that this is very different from this:

```
newAtomicNum = 2;
atomicNum = document.getElementById("atomicNumber").firstChild;
atomicNum.nodeValue = newAtomicNum;
```

...which updates the value. The reason that works is that on the second line, the value we're copying into `atomicNum` is an object reference. Then we *use* that reference on the third line, assigning to one of the object's properties.

Comment: So you have to change an object's value, I need to change a reference to it, not the present value?

Comment: @user3287384: Objects have *properties*, which have values. You don't need a variable at all, you could just do this: `document.getElementById("atomicNumber").firstChild.nodeValue = 2;` The key thing to remember is that when you're doing an assignment like `a = b`, it's a *value* that gets copied. You're not creating any link between `a` and `b` at all. So `a = 2; b = a; b = 3;` leaves `2` in `a`, assigning to `b` doesn't change what's in `a`.

Comment: @user3287384: Sometimes people get confused with object references (which are values) because it *seems* like `b` can affect `a`: `var a = {foo: 2}; b = a; b.foo = 4; console.log(a.foo); // 4` But notice that we **didn't** change `b`. `b` still has the same value it had. What we changed was a property on the object that the value in `b` refers to. The value in `a` *also* refers to that same object, and so `a.foo` and `b.foo` are the same property.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I got this: you can change an object's property by changing the value using a reference to it, or by directly changing the property value; but not by assigning a new value using a variable(which is not a reference nor the property itself)? (this is making my head hurt)